# Excel COM Add-in not loaded after using Visual studio performance profiler

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013, excel-2010, add-in, profiler

My C# Excel Add-in was soft disabled after running the performance profiler of visual studio 2013. Excel displays the following error message:

Load behavior: Not loaded. A runtime error ocurred during the loading of the COM Add-in.

Checking the checkbox in the COM Add-ins Dialog to activate it doesn't work. I've seen similar questions about the add-ins (although there was no mention to the profiler on them) but none of the proposed solutions worked for this case.

Addinional notes:

- Adding an environment variable “VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS” with the value 0 to see error details of the error didn't work.
- Editing the LoadBehavior of the add-in in the registry from 2 to 3 doesn't fix it cause it will gets set to 2 again when Excel starts.

How can I get Excel to load the add-in again? Any tip on how to debug the runtime error?

Comment: Use [this trouble-shooter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx) to get somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried those and nothing worked for me so I ended up reinstalling Microsoft office.